# How to use custom fonts with CSS in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm going to lose my mind now. I am unable to connect my font in css styles for a label in my javafx project. I just don't know what the matter is, the stylesheet is connected correctly, because I can change the color of the label. I put the font file in the same directory as the stylesheet, tried even specifying the absolute path. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?
Java 11, JavaFX 16.

And yes, I checked all the titles and the name of the font. Everything matches

CSS

```
    @font-face {
    src: url("Lobster-Regular.ttf");
}

.label {
    -fx-font-family: "Lobster";
}
```

FXML:

```
<Label id="main_label" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="47.0" stylesheets="@styles/lable.css" text="Test" textFill="WHITE">
</Label>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwHf5.png)

Comment: Have you tried configuring the font for your host OS as a first step to get your app running successfully? Then after that concern yourself with bundling the font.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, I have already installed the font on my OS

Comment: A lot of these resource issues end up being path problems.  It's not clear where your font file is, and if it would find it.  Using Gradle, I put my fonts in src/main/resources/fonts and then specify src: url('/fonts/FontName.TTF') and it works.

Comment: @DaveB At that time, the font file was in the same directory as the css file. It is currently under the path srs / resources / font / Lobster-Regular.ttf

Comment: OK so now try:  src: url('/font/Lobster-Regular.ttf')